# jQuery Cant remove li once added

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, addition

When I add in a new `<li>` into the list, and then I try to remove it, it won't let me remove newly added features from the list?

http://jsfiddle.net/43nWM/

Cheers

Comment: Not regarding to your problem but please notice , I'm using Chrome so I can tell you that: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause when the browser is reading your javascript code the dynamically added li isn't in the DOM, so it can't find it. Instead add the handler to the parent, and listen for the a like this:

```
$('#cblist').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/43nWM/3/

Comment: is there a way to have a link saying "remove all" then for an alert to appear with Are you sure? Yes / Cancel. then for it to remove all the li's in the list on the left?

Answer (score 2):

You can try.

http://jsfiddle.net/43nWM/1/

```
    $(function(){
      $('#cblist a').live('click', function(){
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: live function should not be used

Comment: .live() method is deprecated as you can see on jQuery documentation

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event only to current 'remove' links, not future ones. Use event delegation for this, to cover both bases. Change:

```
  $('#cblist a').click(function(){
```

to

```
  $('#cblist').on('click', 'a', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret here is **event delegation**. When you call `.click(function() {...})` or `.on('click', function() {...})` that event handler is only assigned to elements that matched the selector **when the code was run**. It won't affect elements that are added later.

However, you can use event delegation to assign an event handler to a static element that will contain all of your dynamic elements, which will run the callback function whenever an element matching the dynamic selector triggers that type of event:

```
$('#cblist').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Take a look at the section titled **Direct and delegated events** in the documentation for the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
     $('#cblist').on('click','a',function(){
         $(this).parent('li').remove();
         return false;
     });
});
```

View this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43nWM/6/)

Comment: Making the javascript listen to every click and then search the entire DOM for '#cblist a' isn't such a good idea. But yea it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the on() function, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/43nWM/12/

To be honest, I actually prefer the other two solutions here though.

EDIT: Use on() instead. I originally proposed using live()

Comment: The `.live()` function has been deprecated for **months**, so nobody should be writing new code that uses it.

Comment: live function should not be used.. for reasons that it has been deprecated and its it not good performance wise

Comment: @ParvSharma In practice, calling `$('selector').live('event', function() {...})` in jQuery 1.7+ will call `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {...})`. The main reason not to use deprecated functions is that they could theoretically be removed from future versions, breaking your code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - yeah i know tht

Answer (score 0):

you should add this code to for addition on dynamic `li` tags

```
$li = $('<li>'+name+'</li>');
$a = $('<a href="">remove</a>');
        $a.click(function(){
          $(this).parent('li').remove();
          return false;      
        });
$li.append($a);
```

i have also updated the code on jsfiddle