# li append to existing ul but old functionality doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, html-lists, append

I have an `ul` with some `li`. In `li` a have a `button`. When I click it, it shows me a message. When I try to do something like this: `$("#myUl").append("<li> <div id="click">Click</div></li>");`
it doesn't work on the new li added! Can you help me?

Comment: How are you attaching the click event on the button? You'll have to do the same for the newly added content. Can you share your html code?

Comment: Consider adding the script and html.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794624/jquery-cant-remove-li-once-added/11794767#11794767

Comment: Note that if you are adding that code multiple times, your are breaking the DOM by having the same `id` on more than 1 element.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind the function to the parent `<ul>`, rather than the `<li>` itself

So if you are using:

> $('li').click(function(){});

You should use

> $('ul').on('click','li',function(){});

Comment: For older version of jQuery (pre 1.7), use `$('ul').delegate('li','click',function(){})`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the new link doesn't work after it has been added to the DOM. If this is the case you should use something like

```
$('ul li').on('click', '#click', function() {
    // Handle here
});
```

Read about the on() handler at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1):

Your functionality will work perfectly if you will append the content and after that for functionality if you will be using jquery : [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

like 
`$("ul").on("events",function(){
  $(this).to_be_fired_event();
 });`

Because the `< li >` tag is added dynamically.

Comment: The live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7. on() is recommended instead.

Comment: I have added the answer on August 12 where jquery on was on ```beta``` mode. Now i have updated.